# Errors in publishing rPresentation slidedeck

Tags: r, rstudio, slidify

Have published in rPubs the following codes of rPresentation.
Some of the charts are not displaying properly. Just wondering what I am missing ?Guidance in this regard will be helpful.
Thanks
Link of presentation : http://rpubs.com/shan/Presentation3

````
 Charts

 ========================================================

 ### Lets display some charts.

  ```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}
  library(rCharts)
  library(ggplot2)
   n1 <- nPlot(carat ~ cut , group = "color", data = diamonds[1:40,], type = "multiBarChart")
   n1
  ```

  Plot

 =============================================================

 ### Plotting Chart from economics dataset

 ```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA}

 library(rCharts)
 data(economics, package = 'ggplot2')
 econ <- transform(economics, date = as.character(date))
 m1 <- mPlot(x = 'date', y = c('psavert', 'uempmed'), type = 'Line',data = econ)
 m1$set(pointSize = 0, lineWidth = 1)
 m1
 ```

 Plot

============================================================

 ### Lets plot some Geographical Data
 ```{r gvisMergeExample, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
 library(googleVis)
 Geo <- gvisGeoChart(Exports, locationvar='Country', colorvar='Profit',
 options=list(height=300, width=350))
 Tbl <- gvisTable(Exports, options=list(height=300, width=200))
 plot(gvisMerge(Geo, Tbl, horizontal=TRUE))
 ```

 Plot

 =========================================

 ### Lets plot Fruit vs Year
 ```{r MotionChartExample, results='asis', tidy=FALSE}
 library(googleVis)
 M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, 'Fruit', 'Year', options=list(width=400, height=350))
plot(M)
```
````

Comment: Why do people think adding blank lines helps readability?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Sorry for the inconvenience. Actually, I took it directly from my RPres file asis, incase someone want to try the code.